# How to be rid of mosquito larvae in bird bath

Tags: cleaning, substitute-tool, water, pest-control

I have a birdbath and in the summer it accommodates many mosquitos' eggs. It's concrete, so I would rather not pour it out each time. I also don't want to poison the water as to not harm the birds. I hope to deter the occasional roaming Zikachu, thanks!

Comment: The methods of mosquito control are common and well establish, so unless you have some unusual situation that requires thinking "outside the box", this doesn't really need a life hack within the context of *this* site.

Comment: Incidentally, mosquito control in this scenario is reasonably on topic on our Gardening site; others may be on topic on Outdoors SE. But this has already been answered here: **[How do I keep mosquitos out of my fountain?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1039/85)**

Comment: @RobertCartaino I would rather not poison the water, and fish aren't an option

Comment: I think it's a fine question to ask here.  I assume that it being concrete makes it too heavy.  You want to push the water out, you could use a broom.  I typically have a hose in my hand when I'm changing the water, so I put my thumb over the top and use the pressurised stream to rinse the bath out.